# Diagonals of cyclic quadrilateral

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

A Problem from BDMO $2008$ National.

> $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral. The diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $E$. $AB=39$; $AE=45$; $AD=60$; $BC=56$. Find the length of $CD$.

[image]
Since $ABCD$ is a cyclic quadrilateral So, Ptolemy's theorem can be used. But before using it I have to find the lengths of the diagonal. But I don't know how to. Any Hint will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $\triangle ADE \sim \triangle BCE$. Therefore, we know $|BE|=45\cdot \frac{56}{60} = 42$.

We also know $\triangle ABE \sim \triangle DCE$. Therefore $|DE|=45x$, $|CE|=42x$ and $|CD|=39x$.

Now, Ptolemy's theorem gives $60 \cdot 56 + 39 \cdot 39x = (45+42x)(42+45x)$. Solving this gives us $x=\frac7{15}$, and hence $|CD|=18.2$.

As for why this doesn't match the picture: Because your picture is inaccurate. That line with length 45 is smaller than the one with length 39.

Comment: How do you know $\triangle ADE$ and $\triangle BCE$ are similar?

Comment: @Tebbe It is just a standard fact about quadrilaterals, but if you want a proof, use the theorem that says that $\angle ADB = \angle ACB$, and $\angle ADB = \angle ACB$. I can't find its English name, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, of course, inscribed angles.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can also use **Law of cosines**

EB = 45/60*56 = 42 // opposite triangles similar

Triangle AEB: 39^2 = 42^2 + 45^2 - 2*42*45*cos(∠AEB)
cos(∠AEB) = 0.6
cos(∠AED) = -0.6  // supplementary angle

Triangle AED, with sides (60, 45, 45x) scaled down to (4/3, 1, x)

$$(\frac{4}{3})^2 = x^2 + 1 - 2*x*(-0.6)$$

(x + 0.6)^2 = 16/9 - 1 + 0.6^2 = 256/225 = (16/15)^2
x = 16/15 - 0.6 = 7/15

CD = 39x = 18.2

Comment: Welcome on the MathSE! Note, we support Latex and many voters expect it.