# Quadrilateral ABCD is inscribed in circle, $AB=4, BC=5, CD=6, DA=7$, how long is $AC$?

Tags: circles, quadrilateral

Quadrilateral ABCD is inscribed in circle, $AB=4, BC=5, CD=6, DA=7$, how long is $AC$?

I think I'm probably supposed to use Ptolemy's to solve this, but I don't know if it's possible. Is there a way to do this problem using Ptolemy's?

Comment: Is this... not just standard application of Ptolemy's?

Comment: Isn't Ptolemy's $ef=ac+bd$, where a, b, c, d are sides and e and f are diagonals?

Comment: @Certainlynotadog Ptolemy's gives the product of the diagonals, but don't you need something else to get the individual diagonals?  Am I overlooking something?

Comment: I misread the question. Apologies.

Comment: Similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1637652/diagonals-of-cyclic-quadrilateral?rq=1

Comment: Angles $B$ and $D$ are supplementary, so I think you can use the law of cosines on AC twice.

Comment: "Angles B and D are supplementary, so I think you can use the law of cosines on AC twice. "  But that's always true.  So we can always do this?  This *is* a standard application of Ptolemy's?  ... I'm seeing nothing wrong with this ... but i'm wondering why this isn't a standard solution corolary to Ptolemy's...

Answer (score 1):

By the theorem of cosines we get
$$AC^2=4^2+5^2-2\times 4\times 5\cos(\beta)$$
$$AC^2=7^2+6^2-2\times7\times6\cos(180^{\circ}-\beta)$$ and $$\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos(x)$$